# Smoothing algorithm for map tiling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, math

I'm using JsIso (found it on github) to (hopefully) make a fun little browser game. I modified the hardcoded values for a height map, into a variable and function to generate terrain randomly. What I would like to do, but can't picture in my head at all, is to have a given tile no more or less than 2 levels different than the tile next to it, getting rid of towers and pits.

This is my current code:

```
 var tileHeightMap = generateGround(10, 10); //Simple usage

function generateGround(height, width)
{
 var ground = [];
 for (var y = 0 ; y < height; y++) 
 {
   ground[y] = [];
   for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) 
   {
       ground[y][x] = tile();
   }  
 }
 return ground;

 function tile()
 {
   return (Math.random() * 5 | 0);
 }
}
```

It looks like it would be best to modify the tile function, perhaps passing it the value of the previous tile, and not the generate ground function. If more info is needed, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a two-dimensional [Value Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_noise).

It basically works like this:

Octave #1: Create a number of random points (8, for example) that are evenly spaced in x direction and interpolate between them (if you choose linear interpolation, it could look like this):

[image: First step]

Octave #2: Do the same thing as in #1, but double the amount of points. The amplitude should be the half of the amplitude in #1. Now interpolate again and add the values from both octaves together.

Octave #3: Do the same thing as in #2, but with the double amount of points and an amplitude that is the half of the amplitude in #2.

Continue these steps as long as you want.

This creates a one-dimensional Value Noise. The following code generates a 2d Value Noise and draws the generated map to the canvas:

```js
function generateHeightMap (width, height, min, max) {

  const heightMap = [], // 2d array containing the heights of the tiles
        octaves = 4,    // 4 octaves
        startFrequencyX = 2,
        startFrequencyY = 2;

  // linear interpolation function, could also be cubic, trigonometric, ...
  const interpolate = (a, b, t) => (b - a) * t + a;

  let currentFrequencyX = startFrequencyX, // specifies how many points should be generated in this octave
      currentFrequencyY = startFrequencyY,
      currentAlpha = 1, // the amplitude
      octave = 0,
      x = 0,
      y = 0;

  // fill the height map with zeros
  for (x = 0 ; x < width; x += 1) {
    heightMap[x] = [];
    for (y = 0; y < height; y += 1) {
      heightMap[x][y] = 0;
    }
  }

  // main loop
  for (octave = 0; octave < octaves; octave += 1) {
    if (octave > 0) {
      currentFrequencyX *= 2; // double the amount of point
      currentFrequencyY *= 2;
      currentAlpha /= 2; // take the half of the amplitude
    }

    // create random points
    const discretePoints = [];
    for (x = 0; x < currentFrequencyX + 1; x += 1) {
      discretePoints[x] = [];
      for (y = 0; y < currentFrequencyY + 1; y += 1) {
        // create a new random value between 0 and amplitude
        discretePoints[x][y] = Math.random() * currentAlpha;
      }
    }

    // now interpolate and add to the height map
    for (x = 0; x < width; x += 1) {
      for (y = 0; y < height; y += 1) {
        const currentX = x / width * currentFrequencyX,
              currentY = y / height * currentFrequencyY,
              indexX = Math.floor(currentX),
              indexY = Math.floor(currentY),

              // interpolate between the 4 neighboring discrete points (2d interpolation)
              w0 = interpolate(discretePoints[indexX][indexY], discretePoints[indexX + 1][indexY], currentX - indexX),
              w1 = interpolate(discretePoints[indexX][indexY + 1], discretePoints[indexX + 1][indexY + 1], currentX - indexX);

              // add the value to the height map
              heightMap[x][y] += interpolate(w0, w1, currentY - indexY);
      }
    }
  }
 
  // normalize the height map
  let currentMin = 2; // the highest possible value at the moment
  for (x = 0; x < width; x += 1) {
    for (y = 0; y < height; y += 1) {
      if (heightMap[x][y] < currentMin) {
        currentMin = heightMap[x][y];
      }
    }
  }
  
  // currentMin now contains the smallest value in the height map
  for (x = 0; x < width; x += 1) {
    for (y = 0; y < height; y += 1) {
      heightMap[x][y] -= currentMin;
    }
  }
  
  // now, the minimum value is guaranteed to be 0
  let currentMax = 0;
  for (x = 0; x < width; x += 1) {
    for (y = 0; y < height; y += 1) {
      if (heightMap[x][y] > currentMax) {
        currentMax = heightMap[x][y];
      }
    }
  }
  
  // currentMax now contains the highest value in the height map
  for (x = 0; x < width; x += 1) {
    for (y = 0; y < height; y += 1) {
      heightMap[x][y] /= currentMax;
    }
  }
  
  // the values are now in a range from 0 to 1, modify them so that they are between min and max
  for (x = 0; x < width; x += 1) {
    for (y = 0; y < height; y += 1) {
      heightMap[x][y] = heightMap[x][y] * (max - min) + min;
    }
  }
  
  
  return heightMap;
  
}

const map = generateHeightMap(40, 40, 0, 2); // map size 40x40, min=0, max=2
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
for (let x = 0; x < 40; x += 1) {
  for (let y = 0; y < 40; y += 1) {
    const height = map[x][y];
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + height * 127 + ', 127, 127)';
    // draw the tile (tile size 5x5)
    ctx.fillRect(x * 5, y * 5, 5, 5);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

<del>Note that the values in this height map can reach from -2 to 2. To change that, change the method that is used to create the random values.</del>

#### Edit:

I made a mistake there, the version before the edit reached from -1 to 1. I modified it so that you can easily specify the minimum and maximum value.

First, I normalize the height map so that the values really reach from 0 to 1. Then, I modify all values so that they are between the specified min and max value.

Also, I changed how the heights are displayed. Instead of land and water, it now displays a smooth noise. The more red a point contains, the higher it is.

By the way, this algorithm is widely used in Procedural Content Generation for games.

If you want further explanation, just ask!

Comment: I understood your code *just* well enough to combine it with my own, but the array returned almost always returns all values between 0.5 and -0.5. If I run the code enough times, I'll get a few "1"'s. What values in this poetry would I modify to set the minimum and maximum heights? If you need my full code let me know. The smoothing I asked for, definitely works though, thank you, awesome answer!